# updatepanel and updateprogress flush out PDF response

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Am trying to use UpdatePanel & Updateprogress to show waiting message whiles PDF is created and flushed out. See code

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
  <ProgressTemplate>
    Loading.......
  </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BT_Create" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>   
    <asp:LinkButton ID="BT_Create" runat="server" OnClick="BT_Create_Click">Download</asp:LinkButton>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void BT_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] downloadBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(htmlCodeToConvert, baseUrl);
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="test.pdf; size=" + downloadBytes.Length.ToString());
    response.Flush();
    response.BinaryWrite(downloadBytes);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
}
```

Problem is I can get the waiting message to appear but no PDF is return :S. Any help on this matter ?

Cheers.

Comment: looks like you are sending the file as content to the update panel. That wont work.

Comment: This would be so simple to do with Javascript, it is a matter of showing and hiding two divs, and you don't have to use an update panel and scriptmanager at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to `Response.BinaryWrite` to an update panel, which can't be done. You can only send html back to an update panel.

Please review this [link](http://mohyuddin.blogspot.com/2008/07/responsewritreresponsebinarywritre-and.html) which explains the problem and provides a simple solution.